# SSH proxying for Gitlab

Tags: git, docker, ssh, proxy, gitlab

I have an issue with my GitLab self-hosted instance. The said GitLab server is installed in a Docker container on a server at my home, exposing it's SSH server on port 2222. A Raspberry Pi is used as a proxy between my router and the server.

[(Sketch of my network layout)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bibth.png)

I would be looking for a way to setup a proxy (if possible) for all the incoming SSH connections from `git.<my domain url>` to be redirected to `<my server local ip>:2222` just like HTTP requests are proxied by an nginx server.

At this point, accessing the GitLab server via HTTP works perfectly (due to an nginx proxy on the Pi), but performing git actions via SSH fails.

Issuing `ssh -p 2222 git@<server ip>` works perfectly, and reaches the SSH server of the Docker container.

Comment: Why do you need a proxy? Why can't you just forward the port using iptables, like the router does under the hood?

Comment: I need to be able to SSH to the Raspberry Pi. The incoming connections should be forwarded to the server on port 2222 only if they come from `git.<domain>`, all other traffic remaining unchanged.

Comment: I am not sure how to do that. Would it be possible to use two different ports instead?

Comment: I'm not sure if GitLab is able to handle that. Would be the easiest answer though. Thank you for your suggestion !